# snail matrix arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix

I'm looking for a function to do this,

```
test(3);
#result
3333333
3222223
3211123
3210123
3211123
3222223
3333333

test(1)
#result
111
101
111
```

What i'm trying is this, but i could find any relation between i and n in 
    each loop. Couldn't you please show me algorithm ?

```
    function test(n) {
      return Array.from({ length: (n * 2) + 1 }, () => {
        return Array.from({ length: (n * 2) + 1 }, (item, i) => {
          return i;
        })
      });
    }

    test(3)
```

result:

```
[ [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
  [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
  [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
  [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
  [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
  [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ],
  [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ] ]
```

Comment: "snail matrix javascript" as web search terms may help you.

Comment: could not! because it has some differences

Comment: Then tell us how and why. Show your research so we don't have to make as many assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

You were not a million miles away from making this work.

You can capture the outer array index(y), and the inner array index(x),.
With these 2 values you can work out what wants to go in cell x,y..

eg..

```js
function test(n) {
  return Array.from({ length: (n * 2) + 1 }, (_, y) => {
    return Array.from({ length: (n * 2) + 1 }, (_, x) => {
      return Math.max(
        x > n ? x - n : n - x,
        y > n ? y - n : n - y
      );
    })
  });
}

const ret = test(3);
ret.forEach((i) => {
  console.log(i.join(""));
});
```